# Error submitting login form to external website through c#

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to login to a website and submit a form once logged into the website.

I've tried looking through all the input fields and adding it to the code but still no luck.

The website I'm trying to login to is http://sythe.org/login/

Here's what I currently have:

```
string formUrl = "http://www.sythe.org/login/"; 
string formParams = string.Format("login={0}&password={1}&_xfToken={2}&register={3}&remember={4}&cookie_check={5}&redirect={6}", "", "", "", "0", "1", "1", "https://sythe.org");
string cookieHeader;
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Method = "POST";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
{
     os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
string pageSource;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
{
      pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
Console.WriteLine(pageSource);
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: Maybe if you actually tell us what the error is, someone might be able to help you.Just saying "Error submitting login form" isn't much help.

Comment: @Steve it's not logging in.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code which is generated using the C# plugin for Fiddler:

```
private void MakeRequests()
{
    HttpWebResponse response;

    if (Request_www_sythe_org(out response))
    {
        response.Close();
    }
}

private bool Request_www_sythe_org(out HttpWebResponse response)
{
    response = null;

    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.sythe.org/login/login");

        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "max-age=0");
        request.Headers.Add("Origin", @"https://www.sythe.org");
        request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", @"1");
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36";
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3";
        request.Referer = "https://www.sythe.org/";
        request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate, br");
        request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8");
        request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, @"__cfduid=de8826b5a5df064d6f2ccf2d0952ce52d1554285418; _ga=GA1.2.1744286790.1554285420; _gid=GA1.2.1835584013.1554285420; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; sythe_bug_token=c0FFSCNAJio4MzJnZWEjWXlaV1NCempSdWFrUzRnUHVZUXJKOENicnkwSmZFTXROR1M3MDhUR1ovWTFIVmlvRFZaaVN2MjFHRWtaM2JhT0N1bTJHbEdGSG5VY1dUNjdmVGNZd1RoekNmTmgzaHB4T29OTTZkNytJQWh3cDdjeWlndWpidkJFY0NiRXF4b1ljSVJhN2VGVVd2eEsvK2hrak1pclhvYjRFeWRhT09UUU5seXZDUVlETDlYWUUyazZGajRub3VWV0k5aVhkVVJiWUtxcFRuaTljRElnWEVKd2o4T3ZSZlRheFEzRWRzekgxSXN4d0doMS9YRFR6L1d0OGRONUVLcDZHUEN3eVFRWEQ%3D; _gat=1; xf_session=63943f38ebba0827a4208d363cae5dcb");
        request.Headers.Add("AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH", @"AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0.3");

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

        string body = @"login=testtest%40testtest.testtest&register=0&password=testtesttesttest&remember=1&cookie_check=1&redirect=%2F&_xfToken=";
        byte[] postBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
        request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        stream.Close();

        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
        else return false;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        if(response != null) response.Close();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. I've done this and tried to output it but all I receive is special characters. How do I know if it really submitted and actually logged in?

Comment: If you do receive true, that means you can send the required data for a successful login. Every website is different and might have different set of protections in place and that code is just to give you an idea. You will certainly have to make edits to be able to make further requests.

Comment: If you just receive a special character, then you can safely remove request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate, br"); or  request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"); to see what you get

Comment: And btw, as I said this is just to give you an idea; It is better to use an instance of awaitable HttpClient for web requests in future.

Comment: Okay so, it's still not logged in. Returns the homepage but as not logged in.

Comment: Why are you sending a Cookie Header and another for Alexa Toolbar?

Comment: @Steve as I said, this is a direct extract of the code generated by the plugin

Comment: Im down voting this because it offers no context on why it is the correct answer apart from being auto generated.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace  `string formUrl = "http://www.sythe.org/login/";` to  `string formUrl = "http://www.sythe.org/login/login";`